# Bash shell script function gives "find: missing argument to `-exec'" error

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a function in a Bash shell script to search a Linux tree for filenames matching a pattern containing a regular expression, with colour highlighting:

```
function ggrep {
 LS_="ls --color {}|sed s~./~~"
 [ -n "$1" -a "$1" != "*" ] && NAME_="-iname $1" || NAME_=
 [ -n "$2" ] && EXEC_="egrep -q \"$2\" \"{}\" && $LS_ && egrep -n \"$2\" --color=always \"{}\"|sed s~^B~\ B~" || EXEC_=$LS_
 FIND_="find . -type f $NAME_ -exec sh -c \"$EXEC_\" \\;"
 echo -e \\e[7m $FIND_ \\e[0m
 $FIND_
}
```

e.g. `ggrep a*` lists all files starting with `a` under the current directory tree,

and `ggrep a* x` lists of files starting with `a` and containing `x`

When I run it, I get:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

even though I get the correct output when I copy and paste the line output by "echo" into the terminal. Can anyone please tell me what I've done wrong?

Secondly, it would be great if `ggrep * x` listed all files containing `x`, but `*` expands to a list of filenames and I need to use `\*` or `'*'` instead. Is there a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule, putting commands as strings into shell variables and running them later is going to cause lots of quoting pain.  I would advise finding another way to solve your problem.  If you must store commands in variables, use [arrays](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-array-tutorial/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eval $FIND_
```

in the last line of the function body works fine for me.

Expansions in BASH are generally not recursive, so if you load a command from a variable, you should always use "eval" to enforce reprocessing the expanded variable as it was a fresh input. Normally quotes  are not handled properly within a string that has already been expanded.

To your second problem, I think there is no satisfactory solution. The shell will always expand * before passing it to anything controlled by you. You can disable this expansion, but that is a global setting. Anyway, I think that this expansion could actually act in favor of your function. Consider rewriting it in a way that takes advantage of it. (I did not analyze whether the current version was close to that or not.)

Comment: Well done, Tomasz: eval solves the problem! Thanks too for explaining the * expansion. Guess I've to use a different symbol to save some typing...

Answer (score 2):

Terminate the `find` command with `\;` instead of `\\;` .

```
find . -type f $NAME_ -exec sh -c \"$EXEC_\" \;
```

Comment: Thanks, Avinash, but I get the same error. In fact, having from 1 to 4 (inclusive) backslashes gives the same result (same echo output too).

Comment: of course. you're doing it within quotes, so there's no need to escape `;` at all.

Comment: Thanks, too, Karoly. Not having the backslash gives "--color: 1: --color: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string" for each file in the tree.

Comment: Have you tried `find . -type f $NAME_ -exec sh -c \"$EXEC_\" {} \;`?

Comment: So...let's wait for @Gnubie

Comment: Sorry, evilive. {} is substituted with the path name, but I'm using the path name in other places inside $EXEC_ instead of just the end of $EXEC_. Tomas's answer below works.